# Where do you write VBA code in Visio 2013

Tags: vba, windows-7-x64, visio

There are a lot of tutorials for automating Visio via VBA, but none of them address **where** the code is supposed to go. For example, in Excel, you can right click the worksheet tab and select the option "View Code". This will open a text editor window and you can insert your code there.

Is there such a text/code editor for Visio? If not, where do I add my VBA code to Visio?

Answer (score 1):

In just about any Microsoft office productivity tool Alt+F11 will open the VBA code editor.  Just create or open a file and then hit Alt+F11.  I don't have Visio 2013 but it works in 2010.

Comment: Excellent tip. Please update response to address what happens if developer mode is not enabled

Comment: The keyboard shortcut should work even if you aren't in developer mode

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AIPK-nV1xw), essentially you have to enable developer mode like so

1. FILE
2. OPTIONS
3. ADVANCED
4. Under GENERAL
5. Select "Run in Developer Mode"
6. OK
7. Select DEVELOPER on the Ribbon
8. Select "View Code"